# GLib-Error when using apt-get update

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, error-handling

```
(appstreamcli:13767): GLib-CRITICAL **: 08:57:18.126: g_variant_builder_end: assertion '!GVSB(builder)->uniform_item_types || GVSB(builder)->prev_item_type != NULL || g_variant_type_is_definite (GVSB(builder)->type)' failed

(appstreamcli:13767): GLib-CRITICAL **: 08:57:18.126: g_variant_new_variant: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(appstreamcli:13767): GLib-ERROR **: 08:57:18.126: g_variant_new_parsed: 11-13:invalid GVariant format string
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/cache/app-info -a -e /usr/bin/appstreamcli; then appstreamcli refresh-cache > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

Answer (score 14):

Following works for me:

```
apt-get install --reinstall libappstream4
```

Check this thread for details:  https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=906538

Comment: naah. still same

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same exact issue as stated above. my fix was simple go to  `/etc/apt/` and review the `sources.list` file. Ensure that there are no repos in there which are "experimental". Also go into `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` and look for any files with `.list` extensions. Make sure those also don't contain "experimental" or "beta" repositories.

My issue specifically was caused by this repo entry in the `unstable.list` file under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ unstable main
```

I just commented that out and re-ran `apt-get update`. There is no need to reinstall anything if the problem here is specifically with your apt sources. It is extremely dangerous to run the purge and remove command listed in a previous comment.

This is the output from my original problem.

```
root@localhost:~# apt-get update
Hit:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease
Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian unstable InRelease
Ign:3 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
Hit:4 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease
Hit:5 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stretch Release
Ign:6 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
Hit:7 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian stretch Release

(appstreamcli:10995): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_builder_end: assertion '!GVSB(builder)->uniform_item_types || GVSB(builder)->prev_item_type != NULL || g_variant_type_is_definite (GVSB(builder)->type)' failed

(appstreamcli:10995): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_new_variant: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(appstreamcli:10995): GLib-ERROR **: g_variant_new_parsed: 11-13:invalid GVariant format string
Trace/breakpoint trap
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/cache/app-info -a -e /usr/bin/appstreamcli; then appstreamcli refresh-cache > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem in debian buster and found this to work: [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/464928/error-when-executing-scripts-within-chroot-environment/465694)

1. Purge appstream and gnome packages (to be safe, make a list of packages to re-install latter on):

   ```
   # apt-get remove --purge appstream gnome*
   ```

You can use the command `tasksel --list-tasks` to see available desktop options to install.

Comment: are you sure to run `apt-get remove --purge gnome*`? that's will remove all `gnome` packages which to handle Ubuntu Packages Graphical and your link reference is not yet get response another users, is it an good answer or an bad answer!!!

Comment: That's what I did, remove all gnome packages and reinstalled the task-gnome-desktop, that will reinstall the desktop environment back. That fixed the problem.

Comment: I had the same error (while installing a php package) , but I did not have to remove/reinstall gnome to get it solved.

Comment: Would be nice if you publish your solution. Windows like solutions like reinstall things are not good solutions for sure.